# Effect of an intervening conductor between capacitor plates

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance

Given a parallel plate capacitor where the plates are 3 units apart, if an additional plate 1 unit wide is inserted exactly between the plates, is the effect simply to make the plates now appear to be 2 units apart?

I think the answer is no because:

$Cseries = \frac{1}{ \frac{1}{C1} + \frac{1}{C2}} $ (when C = C1 = C2: $Cseries = \frac{C}{2}) $

Parallel plate capacitance is:  $ C = \epsilon0(A/d) $

Substituting $C1 = \epsilon0\frac{A}{(1/3)*d} $ since the 2 new capacitors have 1/3 the gap of the original

$Cseries = (3/2)*\epsilon0(A/d))$

Thoughts?

Comment: Your result proves that the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

The equipotential surfaces inside the parallel plates of the capacitor are planes parallel to the plates of the capacitor.

The additional plate produces an equipotential volume between the plates and so you now have two capacitor in series with the total thickness of dielectric being $2$ units.
Think of that equipotential volume replaced by two plates at the top and bottom of the volume connected by a wire.